# What are the main reasons why some network parameters might become nan after calling optimizer.step in Pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to understand why one or two parameters in my Pytorch neural network occasionally become nan after calling optimizer.step().

I have already checked the gradients after calling .backward() and just before calling the optimizer, and they neither contain nans nor are very large. I am doing gradient clipping, but I don't think that this can be responsible since the gradients still look fine after clipping. I am using single-precision floats everywhere.

This behavior happens randomly every hundred thousand epochs or so, and is proving very difficult to debug. Unfortunately the code is too long to reproduce here and I haven't been able to replicate the problem in a smaller example.

If anyone can suggest possible issues I haven't mentioned above, that would be super helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: One of the main reason is might be related your labels and model predictions while calculating loss function. Better to check your data loader and the image labels and predictions while calculating the loss function.

Comment: I think if it was a problem with the loss function, it would show up in the gradients, no?

Comment: I recommend you before calculating loss, you should print out labels and predictions. then you can decide which of them making this problem occurs. If everything is okay with labels and predictions then you better consider about normalizations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being ignorance on my part: there were Infs in the gradients that were evading my diagnostic code, as I didn't realize Pytorch's .isnan() method doesn't detect them.